# Azure AD Connect Call PowerShell doing sync

Tags: azure-active-directory

Is there any way to call an external script (PowerShell or .exe) doing a Azure AD Connect sync cycle for each user that is sync? I need to call some kind of script to transform a custom attribute and the "Expressions for Attribute Mappings" ([Azure AD Connect sync: Functions Reference | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/reference-connect-sync-functions-reference)) does not have the necessary function to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Azure AD connect sync scheduler is by default run every 30 minutes. In some cases, you might want to run a sync cycle in between the scheduled cycles or you need to run a different type.

Then you could use Delta or Full Sync to manually run a cycle using PowerShell cmdlet, but in this case it assess all objects that are part of Sync scope. More information, [refer this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-sync-feature-scheduler#start-the-scheduler)

Rather, if you need to sync single object then use the [Azure AD Connect Single Object Sync tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-single-object-sync) which is a PowerShell cmdlet that can be used to synchronize an individual object from Active Directory to Azure Active Directory also it generate report which would be useful to investigate and troubleshoot per object synchronization issues.

Comment: Hey @sikumars-msft. Thank you for the feedback. What I ende up doing is a shadow field where I store the transform value, the only sync that field.